# Linear actuator that extends more than its retracted size

Tags: linear-motion, actuator, linear-motors

I'm trying to build my standing desk and has been studying a lot of them, but have not found a CAD or Technical Drawing of them mechanism. Obviously, as an Engineer, I assume that it uses a Lead Screw where the nut is fixed on the part that move. But here is the deal

Every 3D Model and Drawing I made, I was limited by the retracted size of the actuator, so, if the actuator retracted have 10" so the max size of it extended should be 20" (Actually less but disregard). And then I found this DeskHaus, where it retracted have 22.5" and extend 26". How does them do that??

Thanks for any help!

[image]

Comment: See https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/38406/10902

Answer (score 3):

already found an answer :facepalm:. It seens that telescopic linear actuator exists and have two screw inside of another. Here is a demonstration:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CYz1gQG_ijs&ab_channel=thang010146